# Extract non-existent values based on previous months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I HAVE tb1

```
code  Name        sal_month
====  =====       ========
101    john       02/2017
102    mathe      02/2017
103    yara       02/2017
104    sara       02/2017
101    john       03/2017
102    mathe      03/2017
103    yara       03/2017
104    sara       03/2017
101    john       04/2017
103    yara       04/2017
```

In February all of them received salaries as well as March
How do I extract non-existent values based on previous months?

the result should be come

```
code   sal_month
====   =======
102    04/2017
104    04/2017
```

Thank in advance

Comment: How is this related to the [B *programming language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language))? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please explain your output and also add `anything` you might have tried

Answer (score 1):

First I created this table:

```
create table #T(code int, sal_month varchar(10))

insert into #T values(101,'2/2017'),(102,'2/2017'),(103,'2/2017'),(104,'2/2017'),
(101,'3/2017'),(102,'3/2017'),(104,'3/2017'),(101,'4/2017'),(103,'4/2017')
```

Second, I executed this query:

```
SELECT code, Max(sal_Month)
From #T
Where code not in (select code from #T where  sal_Month = (select Max(sal_Month) from #T))
Group by code
```

Then I got the following results:

[image]

*Note: I am using SQL SERVER 2012*

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but if you look at my output the code 102 and 104 are not exists in month of 4/2017, but 101 exists

Comment: The output of my query is the same as you recommended

Comment: @ALDHEEB as you can see in  the result. Only 102 and 104 are showed. They don't exist in the last month

Comment: @ALDHEEB i think that you received many working answers. you have to accept one or you have to reply to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can count salary_month grouped by id, something like this, and select the rows that shows less than 3 times.

```
select code, count (sal_month) from tb1
group by code
having count (sal_month) < 3
```

After that you join with initial table (just to filter the full rows which you need) on code.

So the final query will look like his:

```
select code, sal_month
from tb1 a
join (select code, count (sal_month) from tb1
group by code
having code < 3) X on a.code = X.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [code] INT
   ,[sal_month] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT @DataSource ([code], [sal_month])
VALUES (101, '2/2017')
      ,(102, '2/2017')
      ,(103, '2/2017')
      ,(104, '2/2017')
      ,(101, '3/2017')
      ,(102, '3/2017')
      ,(104, '3/2017')
      ,(101, '4/2017')
      ,(103, '4/2017');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [sal_month]) AS [MonthID]
         ,MAX([sal_month]) OVER () AS [MaxMonth]
    FROM @DataSource DS1
)
SELECT DS1.[code]   
      ,DS1.[sal_month]
FROM DataSource DS1
LEFT JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[code] = DS2.[code]
    AND DS1.[MonthID] = DS2.[MonthID] - 1
LEFT JOIN DataSource DS3
    ON DS1.[code] = DS3.[code]
    AND DS1.[MonthID] = DS3.[MonthID] + 1
WHERE DS2.[code] IS NULL
    AND DS3.[code] IS NOT NULL
    AND DS1.[sal_month] <> DS1.[MaxMonth];
```

[image]

Some notes:

- we need a way to sort the months and it is not easy as you are storing them in very unpractical way; you are not using a date/datetime column and your string is not a valid date; also, the string you are using is not good at all, because if you have `[sal_month]` from different years, we will not be able to sort them; you should think about this - one alternative is to use this format:

  ```
  201512
  201701
  201702
  201711
  ```

  In  this way we can sort by string.
- in the core I am using `ROW_NUMBER` and sorting months as strings;
- the idea is to look for all records, that have not exists in the next month, but have a record in the previous; at the same time, excluded records which are from the last month, as it's not possible for them to have record in the next month;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select tb2.code, tb2.sal_month from tb
right join (
select code, sal_month, datepart(month, sal_month) + 1 as next_sal_month from tb) as tb2
on (tb.code = tb2.code and datepart(month, tb.sal_month) = tb2.next_sal_month)
where tb2.next_sal_month < 5 and tb.sal_month is null
```

In the result set there's one additional record: code 103 didn't receive salary in March, but did so in February, so it is included as well.

Here's [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eaf89/15), to try :)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of more facts about your tables,  create a **cartesian product** of the 2 axes of month & code, then left join the stored data. Then it is easy to identify missing items when **no stored data** exists when **compared to every possible combination**.

You might already have master tables of sal_month and/or code to use, if you do use those, but if not you can dynamically create them using select distinct as seen below.

> ```
> create table tbl1 (code int, sal_month varchar(10))
>
> insert into tbl1 values(101,'2/2017'),(102,'2/2017'),(103,'2/2017'),(104,'2/2017'),
> (101,'3/2017'),(102,'3/2017'),(104,'3/2017'),(101,'4/2017'),(103,'4/2017')
> ```

> ```
> select c.code, m.sal_month
> from ( select distinct sal_month from tbl1 ) m
> cross join ( select distinct code from tbl1 ) c
> Left join tbl1 t on m.sal_month = t.sal_month and c.code = t.code
> Where t.sal_month IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> code | sal_month
> ---: | :--------
>  103 | 3/2017   
>  102 | 4/2017   
>  104 | 4/2017
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f702f5db3be0223486dd039300df9373)*

Comment: Have you tested the `cross join` approach yet? With this approach **every possible combination of month & code** is evaluated against the stored data, then any missing data is easily (and accurately) identified.